# using s3 bucket arn instead of bucket name in aws terraform code pipeline definition

Tags: terraform, aws-codepipeline, mwaa

I want to know if there is a way to use s3 bucket arn instead of bucket name in the following aws code pipeline definition.
I have this imported with terraform and I want to reference the s3 bucket that is being created in another MWAA module.
The problem is, there is no output on the MWAA module for bucket name and it is only returning the bucket arn. I am using cloudposse to create the MWAA environment.

Here is the code for code pipeline definition:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {
    name     = "airflow-pipeline-dev"
    role_arn = "<role arn>"
    tags     = {}
    tags_all = {}

    artifact_store {
        location = "codepipeline-us-east-1"
        type     = "S3"
    }

    stage {
        name = "Source"

        action {
            .....
        }
    }
    stage {
        name = "Build"

        action {
            ....
        }
    }
    stage {
        name = "Deploy"

        action {
            category         = "Deploy"
            configuration    = {
                "BucketName" = "airflow-dev-s3" # <- pass in arn instead?
                "Extract"    = "true"
            }
            input_artifacts  = [
                "BuildArtifact",
            ]
            name             = "Deploy"
            output_artifacts = []
            owner            = "AWS"
            provider         = "S3"
            region           = "us-east-1"
            run_order        = 1
            version          = "1"
        }
    }
}
```

I have other module for mwaa and I can only output bucket arn from there!

Comment: Looking at the [Terraform Codepiple docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/codepipeline#location) you have to provide the S3 name, not the ARN. Just add an s3 bucket name ouput in the other module, and reference it.

Comment: My problem is I cannot have the code for the s3 to create an output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't modify the other module to output the bucket name, you can extract the bucket name from the bucket ARN. The ARN will have the form

`arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>`

so just split the ARN on `:` and take the last (sixth) part of the result:

```
locals {
  bucketname = element(split(":", var.bucket_arn), 5) 
}
```

Refs:

- [S3 bucket ARNs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-arn-format.html)
- [split function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/split)
- [element function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/element)